# What is the purpose of the architecture_independent tag?

Tags: ros, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've read the description in REP 140, but I'm still not clear about the meaning of [architecture_independent](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#architecture-independent) My interpretation was that the package contains no files that require a particular CPU architecture. An example of a non-architecture-independent package would be one that contains C++ source code that accesses data in a manner that requires a little-endian CPU architecture. Since none of my C++ code is that architecture-specific, I've been specifying architecture_independent in my package.xml files. After reading some discussions about architecture_independent, though, I now suspect that it means "This package generates no architecture-specific *object* files at build time." I'd be grateful if someone can provide clarification.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220135/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-architecture_independent-tag?/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tag refers to the built packages. This is used for optimization at packaging time.

Any package with c++ cannot be marked as architecture independent.

I opened a PR with more specifics for the description: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/108

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2